# Pull title out with semantic HTML and CSS grid

Tags: html, css

My dilemma can be summarised with the following:

- I want to preserve the semantic structure of the first example
- I want to lay it out as per the second example

The semantically correct HTML would be to have the `<header>` nested within the `<article>` element, as the heading belongs to the article.

However, for CSS grid to work, the `<header>` has to be a child of the grid container.

Is there a solution to this conflict?

### Semantically correct, doesn't work

```css
.layout {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 8fr; 
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; 
    gap: var(--grid-gap);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "top top"
      "menu content"; 
}

.layout nav {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  grid-area: menu;
}

.layout main {
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-area: content;
}

.layout header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
<nav>
<p>nav</p>
</nav>
<main>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Subtitle</p>
    </header>
    <p>Lorum ipsum content etc</p>
  </article>
</main>
</div>
```

### Semantically wrong, layout is correct

```css
.layout {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 8fr; 
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; 
    gap: var(--grid-gap);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "top top"
      "menu content"; 
}

.layout nav {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  grid-area: menu;
}

.layout main {
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-area: content;
}

.layout header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
<nav>
<p>nav</p>
</nav>
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Subtitle</p>
</header>
<main>
  <article>
    <p>Lorum ipsum content etc</p>
  </article>
</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: contents`

```css
.layout {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 8fr; 
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; 
    gap: var(--grid-gap);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "top top"
      "menu content"; 
}

.layout nav {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  grid-area: menu;
}

.layout main,
.layout article {
  display: contents;
}

.layout header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: top;
}
.layout article > p {
  grid-area: content;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
<nav>
<p>nav</p>
</nav>
<main>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Subtitle</p>
    </header>
    <p>Lorum ipsum content etc</p>
  </article>
</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Steve, your *non-semantic* approach is only non-semantic in as much as the `<article>` is missing a heading... i.e. an `<h2>` in this context.

There's no issue with every `<header>` on your site having a unique `<h1>` on every page. See [MDN docs for header element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/headerhttps://)

So I would use that approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tentative solution, but I'm sure about moving the navigation to within the article (the article could also have TOC navigation, so this feels wrong).

```css
.layout {
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 8fr; 
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; 
    gap: var(--grid-gap);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "top top"
      "menu content"; 
}

.layout nav {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  grid-area: menu;
}

.layout div{
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-area: content;
}

.layout header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area: top;
}
```

```html
<article class="layout">
  <nav>
    <p>nav</p>
  </nav>
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Subtitle</p>
  </header>
  <div>
    <p>Lorum ipsum content etc</p>
  </div>
</article>
```